# How can I pass a variable from PHP to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I have a php page with

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>
```

Then my javascript is

```
var data = "Not Set";
$.get("test.php",function(returnData,requestStatus,requestObject){
    data = returnData;
    alert(data);
});
```

If I navigate directly to the php page on the site, it displays the data that I need.
I just can't seem to get the data into my javascript.

Am I on the right track and if so where am I going wrong?
Or is there an easier way to get the full filepath when working with a server?
Currently if I run document.location.href in my javascript it returns .

http ://127.0.0.1/etc

Comment: There is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines), without Ajax.

Comment: So who voted down my question? Rude!

Answer (score 2):

*The code below will work on ".php" file. NOT ON ".html" file.*

You can use the php variable with [`echo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) in javascript. For example

```
alert('<?=$phpvariable?>');
```

or

```
alert('<?php echo $phpvariable ?>');
```

Comment: alert is just example. so you can understand how to use php variable

Comment: so can I do `alert('<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>');`

Comment: When I use this method, it break my js.

Comment: Try Firefox and see in Developer->Error Console. What error you are getting ?

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: try alert("<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>"); Use double quote for alert instead of single quote,since you are already using single quote in php variable. :)

Comment: When I use double quotes, the alert box pops up but it says `<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>`

Comment: use alert("<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];?>");                 echo statement ends with semicolon

Comment: same situation jey.  it just displays `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>` in the alert box

Comment: Could I be having issues because my javascript is not embedded in my HTML and is a separate file?

Comment: use <script> tag in html file

Comment: Its not feasible to have my script inside the html.

Comment: What is your file extension. php or html ?

Comment: I have a crap load of .html files and a .js file (where i am trying to get the php variable into) and a .php file.

Comment: HAhA, This will never work. PHP don't work on html files. Save the file as php(Offcourse you need to have php installed for that)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are overthinking this. There is hardly any need to use ajax, but of course you can and just `append()` the data from the ajax call to your `$('body')` and jquery will automatically execute things inside a `<script>` tag.

```
var serverRoot = '<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']?>';
```

Comment: This did not work for me either.  I even tried other variations of single quotes and double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

Instead of GET send $.post request and file don't return any thing just write

```
$.post("Requestedfile.php",
{ 
    data :data
},
function(data) {
    if(data == false)
    {
      //do something
    }
    else
    {
      //do somthing 
    }
}
);
```